# Dynamically adding jQuery elements adds as a sibling, not as a child

Tags: jquery

I am trying to dynamically make a nested set of unordered lists using jQuery. What is happening for the nested `<ul>`, the `<li>` are being inserted as a sibling and not as a child.

Here is a simple reproduction which shows the issue:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <script>
            var $ul = $("<ul></ul>");
            $ul.insertAfter($('h1'));

            append($ul);

            function append($theList) {
                var $listItem = $('<li><div>Hello</div></li>');
                var $newUl = $listItem.append('<ul></ul>');
                $newUl.append($('<li>test</li>'));
                $theList.append($listItem);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The resultant DOM is

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <ul></ul>
        <li>test</li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Whereas I would expect it to be:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <ul>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I add the nested `<li>` under the `<ul>`?

**Note** The non-simplified version is recurisve and building the DOM element entirely as a string isn't practical - I need to be able to insert it into the DOM as a child of the `<ul>`.

Comment: var $ul couldn't be used. It won't save the dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$listItem.append('<ul></ul>');
```

this line returns $listItem, not the new "ul" element. Use appendTo.

```
var $newUl = $('<ul></ul>').appendTo($listItem);
```

Comment: Legendary, thanks  exactly what I wanted. Will mark as answer in 5 minutes :)